# How to get either of two strings in Java that is not null and concatenate

Tags: java, string, java-8, concatenation

I have two strings in a list. Now either of them or both of of the strings could be `null`. And I'll be concatenating the string in this list which is not `null`, with another string say `ABC`. It's guaranteed the list would have only two elements and either one or both of the strings will be null.
If both are `null` output will be `nullABC`

My solution looks like this:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] var0) {
        List<String> l = Arrays.asList(null,"sfdafd");
        String str = (l.get(0)!=null ? l.get(0) : l.get(1)) + "ABC" ;
        System.out.println(str); // sfdafdABC
    }
}
```

Comment: So, if both are null you get "nullABC", is this what you want?

Comment: yes @Rocco that's what's expected

Comment: …and it’s impossible that both are non-`null`?

Comment: yes, it's guaranteed as stated

Comment: `Optional.ofNullable(l.get(0)).orElse(l.get(1)) + "ABC"` would do, but I’d rather stay with your original code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stream the list, filter non-null elements and find the first.

If you don't find anything, you can say "use `null` instead":

```
l.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).findFirst().orElse(null)
```

Then just add the `"ABC"` to the end.